# How to create a column in a dataframe based on another value in the row (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-apply

I have the following data:

| country | code | continent | plants | invertebrates | vertebrates | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | AFG | Asia | 5 | 2 | 33 | 40 |
| Albania | ALB | Europe | 5 | 71 | 61 | 137 |
| Algeria | DZA | Africa | 24 | 40 | 81 | 145 |

I want to add a hemisphere column that is determined by the continent that references a list.
I want to do it using a custom function (and not using lambda).

I attempted the following:

```
northern = ['North America', 'Asia', 'Europe']
southern = ['Africa','South America', 'Oceania']

def hem(x,y):
    if y in northern:
        x = 'northern'
        return x
       
    elif y in southern:
        x = 'southern'
        return x
           
    else:
        x = 'Not Found'
        return x

species_custom['hemisphere'] = species_custom.apply(hem, args=(species_custom['continent'],), axis=1)
```

I receive the following error:

`ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`hem` is defined as taking two arguments but in the `apply` you only pass one.  And when you do you are passing the full `continent` column to it.  Probably not what you want.

You could simplify by using nested `numpy` `where`.

```
import numpy as np

df['hemisphere'] = np.where(df['continent'].isin(northern), 'northern', np.where(df['continent'].isin(southern),'southern','Not Found'))
```

**Result**

```
       country code continent  plants  invertebrates  vertebrates  total  hemisphere
0  Afghanistan  AFG      Asia       5              2           33     40    northern 
1      Albania  ALB    Europe       5             71           61    137    northern 
2      Algeria  DZA    Africa      24             40           81    145    southern
```